# How to add chef-client recipe on new born client node (after client register)

Tags: chef-infra

I'm following a guide on registering my client machine in chef server - https://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Configuring+Chef+Client

So I've created my client.rb file with following contents:

```
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
chef_server_url          'https://yourchefserver.com/'
validation_client_name   'chef-validator'
node_name                'myclientname'
```

Then I put above file together with validation.pem into /etc/chef directory.

I've installed .deb chef-client package, that I've downloaded from Chef site.

On first chef-client command run, new born client is correctly registering in my chef server, BUT it gets empty run list. This command is being run "in background" - in fact called from rc.local on new born VM (disk image cloning). So chef-client run occurs exactly one time.

I'm wondering, how could I instruct my new born client to be equipped with recipe "chef-client:service". Or more wide question: how to instruct chef-server to pass any recipes to new born client just after auto registration?

As far as I can see now, I might pass "environment" variable into client.rb file, but this would need to be a kind of temporary environment made just for passing 'chef-client:service' recipe. And in future this environment entry would not be needed.

Any ideas? What is best approach?

Comment: Checkout the documentation on "knife bootstrap". You'll find it to be a more powerful way to setup new chef clients. That link your found is very old (referencing chef 10).

Comment: Thanks for comment. Anyway 'knife bootstrap' is not solution for me. This command works other way: it connects to some host using SSH and do the stuff. And in my situation host is being cloned and started, and it auto register (as mentioned, it calls chef-client 1st time by itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to go is to create a JSON file named whatever you wish and pass it with `-j file.json` for the first run. See [HERE](http://docs.getchef.com/install_bootstrap.html#unattended-installs) for a more complete documentation.

In this file you set the initial runlist like

```
{
  "run_list": [ "recipe[chef-client::service]" ]
}
```

Comment: This method seems strange to me, but in fact it works. I mean it's quite unusual that automation software do not offer a way to instruct newly created node to receive some initial run list. But this is not a problem to specify this one recipe on client-side.

Comment: It does offer a way when you use the tooling aka knife bootstrap. But it also gives you freedom to achieve the same result the way you want with a clean methodology ;) in the json file you can also provide some attributes to drive the recipes. I find it great you can get the same behavior with internal tooling or another way fitting better your personal workflow